# unedined output in javascript alert box

Tags: javascript

I have written simple jsp file which contain textfield for username and password.
I want to validate that field using javascript, but when I write 
var a=document.getElementsByID("uname") and prints length of a, it shows me output as 'undefined'.

here is my code..

```
<head>
<script>
    function validate() {

        var a=document.getElementById("uname");
        alert(a.length);
        return false; 
    }
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/Edzeal/Validate">



        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"></td>
                <td><p id="uerror"></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return validate()"></td>
                <td><input type="reset">&nbsp<a
                    href="/Edzeal/Register.jsp" shape="rect">Register</a></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to alert the 'length' property of the reference to that element. Element objects do not have any such property, unlike arrays or strings, so you are seeing 'undefined'.

See the docs for Elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element

And document.getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

`Element` has no property `length` on it, it being undefined is expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
alert(a.length);
```

to

```
alert(a.value);
```

a is an Element, no the string value of the form field.  You need .value to get that.